# Creation of tiled grid in Java with GeoTools

Tags: java, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I am trying to create a grid using GeoTools in JAVA, covering specific area with resolution 50 m (distance between two points). To do so I have two points: the most northwestern (let's call it NW) and the most southeastern one.

I created a table and put the NW point in tab[0][0]. Starting from tab[0][0] using the Geodetic Calculator ([link to the doc](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html)) I am calculating the next points and putting them in right place into my table.

Here is the code I developed:

```
public void createGrid(double granularity) {
    logger.info(GridManager.class + " creation of grid called");
    
    int defaultCellID = 0;
    float defaultSigLevel = -1000;
    
    /*  __ __ __ __ __ 
     * |NW|__|__|__|NE| 
     * |__|__|__|__|__|
     * |__|__|__|__|__|
     * |SW|__|__|__|SE|
     */

    // mind, this is lon/lat
    Point2D.Double nePoint = new Point2D.Double();
    nePoint.setLocation(sePoint.getX(), nwPoint.getY());

    Point2D.Double swPoint = new Point2D.Double();
    swPoint.setLocation(nwPoint.getX(), sePoint.getY());

    // calculations of a width of the grid
    this.gc.setStartingGeographicPoint(nwPoint);
    this.gc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(nePoint);
    double d = this.gc.getOrthodromicDistance();
    int width = (int) Math.ceil(d / granularity);

    // calculations of a height of the grid
    this.gc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(swPoint);
    d = this.gc.getOrthodromicDistance();
    int height = (int) Math.ceil(d / granularity);

    // grid creation
    grid = new TileCartesian[height][width];
    grid[0][0] = new TileCartesian((float) nwPoint.getY(), (float) nwPoint.getX(), defaultSigLevel, defaultCellID, 0, 0);
    double dist;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        this.gc.setStartingGeographicPoint(grid[i][0].getLon(),grid[i][0].getLat());
        dist = granularity;
        
        for (int j = 1; j < width; j++) {
            
            this.gc.setDirection(90 /* azimuth */, dist);
            
            Point2D.Double p = (Point2D.Double) this.gc
                    .getDestinationGeographicPoint();
            
            grid[i][j] = new TileCartesian((float) p.getY(),
                    (float) p.getX(), defaultSigLevel, defaultCellID, i, j);
            dist += granularity;
        }

        if (i != height-1) {
            this.gc.setDirection(180 /* azimuth */, granularity);
            Point2D.Double p = (Point2D.Double) this.gc
                    .getDestinationGeographicPoint();
            grid[i+1][0] = new TileCartesian((float) p.getY(), (float) p.getX(), defaultSigLevel, defaultCellID, i+1, 0);
        }
    }
    
    
    logger.info(GridManager.class + " Grid created");
}
```

My problem is that the most SE point of the calculated grid is far from the assumed one. And when I am exporting the result to GeoTIFF this cause deformation.

I really do not know how to solve this problem. Maybe there exists any other way to create such a grid, but I couldn't find any solution which would fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I wrote some [code](https://code.google.com/p/spatial-cluster-detection/source/browse/trunk/cluster/src/main/java/org/geotools/clustering/JaiToolsCircle.java) to do this that looks like this:

```
    public JaiToolsCircle(ReferencedEnvelope env, double cellSize) {
      this.env = env;
      this.cellsize = cellSize;
      System.out.println("cellsize " + cellsize);
      height = (int) Math.ceil((env.getHeight() / cellsize))+1;
      width = (int) Math.ceil((env.getWidth() / cellsize))+1;
      System.out.println("width "+width);
      System.out.println("height "+height);
      data = new double[height][width];
      GridEnvelope2D gridEnv = new GridEnvelope2D(0, 0, width, height);

      gg = new GridGeometry2D(gridEnv, (org.opengis.geometry.Envelope) env);
   }
```

I suspect your problem is that GeoTools bounding boxes (ReferencedEnvelope in the above) expect the SW/NE corners of the grid to be specified.

You can then write to the grid using something like:

```
protected final void quantize(Circle c) {
    ClusterKernelFactory.ValueType type = ClusterKernelFactory.ValueType.EPANECHNIKOV; 
    float centreValue = (float) c.getStatistic();
    int radius = (int) (Math.floor(((c.radius + cellsize))) / cellsize);
    System.out.println("radius "+radius+" "+c.radius);
    double x = c.getCentre().getX();
    x = Math.ceil((x + cellsize / 2.0) / cellsize) * cellsize;
    double y = c.getCentre().getY();
    y = Math.ceil((y + cellsize / 2.0) / cellsize) * cellsize;
    DirectPosition2D pos = new DirectPosition2D(x, y);
    DirectPosition2D dest = new DirectPosition2D();
    GridCoordinates2D gridCoords = null;


        try {
            gridCoords = gg.worldToGrid(pos);
        } catch (InvalidGridGeometryException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINER, e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (TransformException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.FINER, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
   System.out.println(gridCoords);
    KernelJAI kernel = ClusterKernelFactory.createCircle(radius, type, 1.0f);
    kernel=KernelUtil.standardize(kernel);
    float[] cdata = kernel.getKernelData();

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
        for (int j = -radius; j <= radius; j++, k++) {
            System.out.println((gridCoords.x+i)+","+(gridCoords.y+j)+" "+cdata[k]);
            data[gridCoords.y+j][gridCoords.x+i]+=cdata[k]*centreValue;
        }
    }

}
```